# I have an oracle table which has date in dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy format in same field. Now i have to convert into one common format

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have an oracle table which has date in dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy format in same field. Now i have to convert into one common format.
Please suggest how to approach this?

I did tried but it is failing as it is failing due to invalid month.
Is there a way i can first identify what format the date is and then based on case statement i might convert.
or something easy way? Please

Comment: Are you sure you don't have values in the `mm-dd-yyyy` format? You will not get an error from different separator characters (unless you force an exact match using the `FX` format model in the conversion) so the error is likely somewhere else and trying to put a month of `13` would give you `ORA-01843: not a valid month`. If you do have dates in both `DD-MM-YYYY` and `MM-DD-YYYY` format then you have **BIG** problems as you cannot know if `01-02-2020` is 1st February or 2nd January.

Answer (score 4):

I trust you've learnt your lesson and you're now going to store these dates in the date data type.

Your two different date formats actually aren't important, Oracle already is a little over accepting when it comes to separating characters.
e.g

```
to_date('01/01/1900','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Does not error

> I did tried but it is failing as it is failing due to invalid month.

Your error is coming because you've allowed a value that doesn't match either of those formats into your string column.

If you are on version 12.2 at least (which you should be in 2020) then you can use the `validate_conversion` function to identify rows that don't convert to a date with your format (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)

```
select string_column
from  my_table
where  validate_conversion(string_column AS DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy') = 0
```

The other additional helper we got in 12.2 was the `on conversion error` clause of `to_date`. So you can do.

```
alter table my_table add my_date date;
update my_table set my_date = to_date(my_string default null on conversion error,'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: Yup, i have learnt the lesson, not to have varchar field to store date-time data, but the existing issue need to be resolve. Thanks for the valuable codes, will work on this. I also liked the idea which @GMB has suggested to relace the '/' with '-' .

Thanks Andrew Sayer

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, the / and - mixup is not actually a problem for Oracle. Both versions can be successfully converted to a date with either separator. Your problem is data is something else - likely where days and months are flipped around as it’s complaining that it can’t convert bits of it to a month. If that’s the case then actually there’s probably some data that has been stored the wrong way round but is still technically valid (01/02/2020 might be Feb or Jan), this is going to be impossible to clean up without more information about the row.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you are confident that there is no other format than those two, a simple approach is `replace()`:

```
update mytable set mystring = replace(mystring, '/', '-');
```

This turns all dates to format `dd-mm-yyyy`.

I would suggest taking a step forward and convert these strings to a `date` column.

```
alter table mytable add mydate date;
update mytable set mydate = to_date(replace(mystring, '/', '-'), 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

This will fail if invalid date strings are met. I tend to consider that a good thing, since it clearly signals that this a problem with the data. If you want to avoid that, you can use `on conversion error`, available starting Oracle 12:

```
to_date(
    replace(mystring, '/', '-') default null on conversion error,
    'dd-mm-yyyy' 
)
```

Then you can remove the string column, which is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks @GMB, for this awesome idea... this looks feasible as the column i am having is of varchar so i can easily use replace function. And later can convert to date-time field. Will try this approach, hope this works.